# windows desktop url shortcuts adding characters in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, desktop, shortcut

Newbie programmer here. I recently started to have an issue opening desktop shortcuts in chrome. We have a internal web page that opens in chrome on the desktop. The path to the page is correct in the shortcut properties. The url looks like this:   
 
path to some local server\name of some file.asp

Recently if the desktop short cuts are opened in chrome the url will show added characters which will look simliar to this:  
path to some local server\name of some file.asplocations=2xsomeotherstuff
  
or we will find a single quotation mark at the end of the url. If the unneeded information is deleted the url opens just fine. How is the url change being injected? How can we alleviate this problem? can we set the amount of characters the url can be?can any kind of programming restrictions be implemented?If so how would they be implemented? Any help is appreciated. 
steps taken: 
1. clean pc  
2. uninstall chrome and left over files  
3. reinstall chrome 
4. check for adware  
5. retype the url in the shortcut properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest 3 possible solutions:

1) Disable location sharing setting in chrome

http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Your-Location-Sharing-Setting-in-Google-Chrome

2) End the url with a ?

3) Try using a shortcut as an application launcher:
path/to/chrome.exe ""
or
path/to/chrome.exe --app=

Comment: would I apply the URL after the --app= within quotation marks? Is there a escape character or ignore everything after a particular point in the url. The "?" is a great suggestion that works however since it is a query character I don't want something accidentally being queried that should not be. "Locations" is just one item I have observed there were other things injected into other urls. This issue seems to be tied to a weather monitoring web page as the injections are part of urls found on that page. weird. thanks.